# Big multidimensional vector initializaton C++

Tags: c++, exception, vector, initializing

I am trying to load simulation results from a file into a vector. The code works well for small and medium amount of data. When I try do load big files I get an exception. The array that makes my program crash is about 17000*7*3000 elements. I've tried splitting initialization into few steps but it has crashed as well. Could you please tell me if I can do something to make it work?

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Import of surface receivers file
    for(int freq=0;freq<7;freq++)
    {
        filePath=filePath_old;

        filePath.Replace(wxT("125 Hz"),wxString::Format(wxT("%i"), freqSTI[freq])+wxT(" Hz"));
        if(importer.ImportBIN(filePath,mainData))
        {
            if(timeTable.size()==0){
                for(int idstep=0;idstep<mainData.nbTimeStep;idstep++)
                {
                    timeTable.push_back(mainData.timeStep*(idstep+1)*1000);
                }
            }
            for(wxInt32 idrs=0;idrs<mainData.tabRsSize;idrs++)
            {
                for(wxInt32 idface=0;idface<mainData.tabRs[idrs].dataRec.quantFaces;idface++)
                {
                    if(tab_wj.size()<idrs+1){
                        tab_wj.push_back(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<wxFloat32> > > (mainData.tabRs[idrs].dataRec.quantFaces,std::vector<std::vector<wxFloat32> >(7,std::vector<wxFloat32>(mainData.nbTimeStep,0.f))));
                    }
                    //Pour chaque enregistrement de cette face
                    int tmp=mainData.tabRs[idrs].dataFaces[idface].dataFace.nbRecords;
                    for(wxInt32 idenr=0;idenr<mainData.tabRs[idrs].dataFaces[idface].dataFace.nbRecords;idenr++)
                    {
                        t_faceValue* faceval=&mainData.tabRs[idrs].dataFaces[idface].tabTimeStep[idenr];
                        tab_wj[idrs][idface][freq][faceval->timeStep]=faceval->energy;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The place where an exception occures is `tab_wj.push_back...`

When I tried to split initialization into more than one step I wrote:

```
std::vector<wxFloat32> t1(mainData.nbTimeStep,0.f);
std::vector<std::vector<wxFloat32> > t2(7,t1);
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<wxFloat32> > > t3(mainData.tabRs[idrs].dataRec.quantFaces,t2);
```

Then it crashed at last one of these lines.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 17000 * 7 * 3000 * 4 bytes (assuming float32 is 4 bytes long) = 1 428 000 000. That's one and a half gigabyte. Perhaps you don't have either enough RAM or sufficient swap space.

Comment: I have 8GB RAM so it should be ok.

Comment: Even though, your 8GBs are not assigned all to your program. I suggest you use valgrind to find the root of your problem.

Comment: Is your exception a `bad_alloc`?

Comment: Is your program a 32-bit or 64-bit application? If you have a few other bits of data and code floating about, 1.5GB is quite likely "more than your application can handle" in a 32-bit application.

Comment: "The place where an exception occures is ..." Can you provide the message that your exception contains?

Comment: Btw when you have to handle such large amount of data a generally good practice is to split it in smaller chunks, work on those and then combine the results to get the final one. You can easily load a part of the data, do what you want to do with it, throw it away, load the next chunk and so on.

Comment: The message is "bad allocation".

Problem with splitting my data into small chunks is that I need to rearrange the dimensions of the data. I have 7 files in each I have n*m records. So what I can easily get is 7 chunks of n*m. What I finally need is array of n*7*m or n chunks of 7*m. To do that I would have to reload the files often what I think would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is getting an exception while allocating memory.
std::vector<> must reallocate its storage as you add new items to it.
It doesn't do this for each push_back() because it allocates more than it needs.
A vector<> of size 5 might actually have space for 8 items (size() vs. capacity()). When you insert the 9th item it must reallocate, and typically it will double its capacity (from 8 to 16 (*)).

This reallocation can fragment your heap.
To improve you can preallocate the vector to the size it will eventually need, so it will never need to reallocate. vector::reserve()
So, if you know you will eventually need 17000*7*3000, reserve this up front.

Also, if you have a lot of small vectors, allocating those at a small size can reduce your memory requirements. Usually vector<> has a default size which could be 8 or 16. If you only ever insert 3 items, then you are wasting a lot of storage. During allocation of the vector I believe you can specify its initial capacity.

Since you are using nested vectors, each of these will in turn have their own allocations. Depending on your version of C++, pushing a vector onto a vector can cause a number of allocations.

You might try restructuring the code to not require nested vectors.

(*): a naive vector implementation will double the allocation size when it needs more space, but a factor of 1.6 is better for a number of reasons (its just as big-O efficient and leads to much less memory fragmentation). See "The golden ratio": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio

Comment: Could you please tell me how to reserve space for multidimensional vector?

Comment: Vector doesn't support multi-dimensions as such. For example, this will create a nested vector of 10 by 20.  Please note the difference between resize() and reserve().
std::vector<std::vector<int>> x;
    x.resize(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        x[i].reserve(20);
    }

Comment: `std::vector<wxFloat32> v(X * Y * Z)` where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the dimensions you want.  Then just use math to figure out the appropriate offset.

Comment: Yeah, what he (chad) said!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it tomorrow!